# Работа с директориями, перемещение файлов

Tags: администрирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переместить все файлы (с разным именем) из папок с одинаковым именем, как показано ниже.
Ниже показана папка АВТОМОБИЛИ, но их две и при этом они находятся в разных директория, а рядом с ней есть другая папка с другим названием.

```
КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА:
        КАРТИНКИ 1:
            АВТОМОБИЛИ:
                1.jpg
                2.jpg
                3.jpg

            МОТОЦИКЛЫ:
                ...

        КАРТИНКИ 2:
            АВТОМОБИЛИ:
                4.jpg
                5.jpg
                6.jpg

            МОТОЦИКЛЫ:
                ...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить вот так:

```
НОВАЯ КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА:
        НОВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ:
            АВТОМОБИЛИ:
                1.jpg
                2.jpg
                3.jpg
                4.jpg
                5.jpg
                6.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```bsh
mkdir -p ./НОВАЯ КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА/НОВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ/АВТОМОБИЛИ'

mv ./"КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА"/"КАРТИНКИ 1"/АВТОМОБИЛИ/*.jpg ./"НОВАЯ КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА"/"НОВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ"/АВТОМОБИЛИ/

mv ./"КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА"/"КАРТИНКИ 2"/АВТОМОБИЛИ/*.jpg ./"НОВАЯ КОРНЕВАЯ ПАПКА"/"НОВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ"/АВТОМОБИЛИ/
```